# Returning values from other Stream inside a Stream

Tags: for-loop, java-8, java-stream

**The task**

I have a list of Objects "Point" and a filtered version of it: allPoints and pointsFromStepTwo, where stepTwo is an other method. I need to add to list, that i got from stepTwo, all Point, which are match to condition that aplied to allPoints and pointsFromStepTwo at the same time.

The code looks kind like:

```
public List<Point> stepThree(List<Point> pointsFromStepTwo, List<Point> allPoints) {
    return allPoints.stream()
            .filter(point -> point.getRadius() + {pointsFromStepTwo.stream().forEach(point1 -> point1.getRadius()); > smth })
}.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where "smth" is a special condition.

**The problem**

I can't find a correct way to return values from pointsFromStepTwo to points from allPoint every time.
Basically it is a for loop inside a for loop. I think that will work:

```
public List<Point> stepThree(List<Point> pointsFromStepTwo, List<Point> allPoints) {
    Set<Point> tmp = new HashSet<>();

    for (Point point1 : allPoints) {
        for (Point point2 : pointsFromStepTwo) {
            if (point1.equals(point2) ||
                    point1.getRadius() + point2.getRadius() + getGap() + getErr() >= getL(point1, point2)) {
                tmp.add(point2);
            }
        }
    }

    return new ArrayList<>(tmp);
}
```

where getL(point1, point2) is a special condition

Comment: how about showing the for loops that pre java-8 would use for this?

Comment: Try `pointsFromStepTwo.forEach(point1 -> {
            allPoints.stream().filter(point1.getRadius() + point2.getRadius() >= getL(point1, point2)).forEach(tmp::add);
        });` but i haven't tested it.

Comment: Is it possible to do that without a local variable? I assumed that tmp in your answer is a local variable List<Point> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Maybe like this `allPoints.stream().map(point1->{
            pointsFromStepTwo.stream().filter(point2 -> point1 + point2 >= getL(point1, point2));
            return point1;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `anyMatch` instead of `forEach`:

```
public List<Point> stepThree(List<Point> pointsFromStepTwo, List<Point> allPoints)
{
    return allPoints.stream()
                    .filter(point2 -> pointsFromStepTwo.stream()
                                                       .anyMatch(point1 -> point1.getRadius() + point2.getRadius() >= getL(point1, point2)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

EDIT: It looks like you want the output `List` to contain all the points of `pointsFromStepTwo`. If you don't care about the order, then (assuming all the points of `pointsFromStepTwo` belong to `allPoints), you can add a condition to the filter:

```
public List<Point> stepThree(List<Point> pointsFromStepTwo, List<Point> allPoints)
{
    return allPoints.stream()
                    .filter(point2 -> pointsFromStepTwo.stream()
                                                       .anyMatch(point1 -> point2.equals(point1) || (point1.getRadius() + point2.getRadius() >= getL(point1, point2))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: @Alexander If you are referring to my second code snippet, I hinted that it might change the order of the elements that belong to `pointsFromStepTwo`, since it doesn't add the elements of `pointsFromStepTwo` separately (as you did with `addAll`). It adds them while iterating over the elements of the `allPoints` List. If you care about the order, you'll have to call `addAll` separately.

Comment: The differense was not in order, but in points themeselves. I allready got it. I've changed the code example with for loop inside a for loop from List to Set and then the answers become identical. Thank you agian.